# sum() column for multiple queries of the same id and display to joined tables

Tags: mysql

can i select the sum of a column and display it to another table joined to it?

```
tblmedstockin
+--------------+-------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
| medstockinid | medid | stockinquantity | stockindate | stockinexpdate |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
|            1 |  1001 |             100 | 2019-01-29  | 2019-12-16     |
|            2 |  1001 |             100 | 2019-01-29  | 2019-12-16     |
|            3 |  1001 |              12 | 2019-01-29  | 2019-01-29     |
|            5 |  1004 |               4 | 2019-01-29  | 2019-01-29     |
|            6 |  1004 |              20 | 2019-01-30  | 2019-01-30     |
```

Expected result:

```
tblmedstock
+------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
| medstockid | medid | category | medname   | stockinquantity | stockcritqty |
+------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
|       1001 |  1001 | Tablet   | Losartan  |             212 |          100 |
|       1004 |  1004 | Tablet   | Metformin |              24 |          100 |
+------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I have multiple rows that i want to sum (stockinquantity) from tblmedstockin and display it as a column on tblmedstock.

Tried this code but have to manually change the id for every query:

```
select a.medstockid, c.medid, c.category, c.medname, (select sum(stockinquantity)from tblmedstockin where medid = 1001) as stockinquantity, a.stockcritqty from tblmedstock a inner join tblmedstockin b on a.medstockinid = b.medstockinid inner join tblmedicine c on a.medid = c.medid where a.medid = 1001

-> union

-> select a.medstockid, c.medid, c.category, c.medname, (select sum(stockinquantity)from tblmedstockin where medid = 1004) as stockinquantity, a.stockcritqty from tblmedstock a inner join tblmedstockin b on a.medstockinid = b.medstockinid inner join tblmedicine c on a.medid = c.medid where a.medid = 1004;
```

can it be done automatically without manually setting the id?

Comment: Are we missing the description of tblmedicine?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join your tables (as-is) and use a GROUP BY here (making some assumptions about your table relationships here):

```
select a.medstockid, c.medid, c.category, c.medname, sum(b.stockinquantity), a.stockcritqty 
from tblmedstock a 
   Removed since this doesn't appear to be used in this query*/
   inner join tblmedstockin b on a.medstockinid = b.medstockinid*/
   inner join tblmedicine c on a.medid = c.medid 
WHERE a.medid in (1001,1004)
GROUP BY a.medstockid, c.medid, c.category, c.medname, a.stockcritqty
```